# Windows 11 - Running WSL I get "The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open."

Tags: powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11

I'm running Windows 11 and normally I can open WSL from Terminal immediately after startup.  But if I try to start Ubuntu-20.04 WSL, I get an error in the terminal:

```
The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open.
```

When I open Windows Powershell, it takes quite a while (at least 5 mins) to actually give me a command line after displaying:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Install the latest PowerShell for new features and improvements! https://aka.ms/PS
```

If I try to run WSL once I get a command line, I get the same error.

I've tried to restart and I am in the same situation.

I did run into this before and found that after 30+ mins I was able to run WSL.
Not sure why though.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The text “The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section”, is typically associated with a file.  Does your error not include one? Have you tried to reset Windows Terminal?

Comment: No file is mentioned, although maybe it's the wsl executable?   I haven't tried anything else with the terminal

Comment: Try and Uninstall and Reinstall WSL.

Comment: I usually like to "start simple" in troubleshooting, but taking 5 minutes to start PowerShell and only being able to run WSL after 30 minutes seems to me to point to something pretty severe.  Is any process in Task Manager ("More Details" selected, of course) showing a large impact on CPU or Disk during this time?  Real-time virus protection or something?

Answer (score 1):

If two Lxss entries(with different GUIDs) point to the same WSL instance(WSL folder, `D:\Ubuntu WSL1 22.04` in my example), then only one instance can be launched. When trying to launch the other instance, wsl.exe assert error:

> The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open.

You can check your registry node `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss` to see whether you are having such problem.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

On Win10.21H2, my experiment shows that, this problem happens only for WSL1 instance. For WSL2 instance, as long as the `BasePath` value is the same for two entries, they will launch the same WSL2 instance.

Comment: Good find!  How did you come across that?

Comment: I'm investigating how to manually register a WSL instance into Windows 10, and find that all secrets reside in the `Lxss` registry key. So I write a bat file to manually do the registration, only needing a WSL storage folder as input. Code at https://github.com/chjfth/dailytools/tree/master/cmd-batch/WSL-green . With my WSL-green.bat I can easily try that conflicting case, and I feel curious whether someone has encountered this very situation, so I searched and find this post.